# Vincular campo select con datos en MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Tengo un formulario en el que los trabajadores tienen que rellenar unos cuantos datos. Estoy intentando que desde un campo `SELECT` puedan seleccionar su nombre y código correspondiente sin tener que escribirlo.

Bases de datos en MySQL:

> **dbo.Personal:** Codigo Nombre Apellido1
>
> **dbo.Control_Tareas:** Matricula Trabajador

La idea es que, desde un campo SELECT se recojan los campos de dbo.Personal y puedan ser seleccionados en el formulario, y que al enviar los datos rellenados en el formulario, éstos pasen a registrarse en la tabla de Control_Tareas.

Estoy desde un servidor linux Fedora en el que me conecto vía PHP a un servidor SQL en Windows.

Estos son los archivos que tengo:

**conectardb.php**

```
<?php

$serverName = "192.168.9.10"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"base_datos", "UID"=>"logdb", "PWD"=>"pwd");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexion establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexion no se pudo establecer.<br /><br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

**form.html**

```
<?php

    include 'conectardb.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="es" >
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'>       

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

      <form action="conectardb.php" method="post">
        <select>
        <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
            <?php
              $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM dbo.Personal");
              while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$valores[Codigo].','.$valores[Nombre].','.$valores[Apellido1].'"></option>;
              }
            ?>
       </select>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Pero el SELECT me sale vacío.

No tengo muchos conocimientos, pero he recorrido bastantes páginas intentando unir un poco todo, pero no ha dado resultado y no sé qué hago mal.

Comment: Independientemente de la solución que te puedan dar, hay un par de errores de sintaxis. El primero es en la línea del "echo" que hay dentro del "while", te falta cerrar las comillas simples al final de esta línea, (después del </option>). El segundo es el cierre de la etiqueta del formulario (</form>"), no veo que estes realizando este cierre y eso te puede dar problemas, si no ahora, sí en un futuro.

Comment: Me he fijado en archivo "conectardb.php" estás usando ```sqlsrv_connect``` para conectarte a una db mysql y la variable de conexion se llama ```$conn``` y en archivo form estás usando una variable que se supone que tiene la conexion llamada ```$mysqli```

Comment: Actualmente tienes `<option value="codigo, nombre, apellido"></option>` con lo que asignas un valor pero no un texto visible: `<option value="valor">Texto visible</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hice un ejemplo de conexión a DB mediante PDO en la que te conectas a tu db y extraes todos los datos de la tabla "personal", espero que te sea de ayuda.

Conexión simplificada PDO.

Archivo "conectardb.php":

```
<?php

function connect()
{
    try {

        $connectionInfo = [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => '192.168.9.10',
            'Database' => 'base_datos',
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'UID' => 'logdb',
            'PWD' => 'pwd'
        ];

        $conn = new PDO(
            $connectionInfo['driver'] . ':
            host=' . $connectionInfo['host'] . ';
            dbname=' . $connectionInfo['Database'] . '; 
            charset=' . $connectionInfo['charset'],
            $connectionInfo['UID'],
            $connectionInfo['PWD']
        );

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $conn;

    } catch (PDOexception $e) {
        die('Error al conectar con la base de datos, ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

$conn = connect();

?>
```

Explicación:

En la variable `$conn` hago una instancia del controlador PDO.

- driver -> Espeficico el driver de conexión que en este caso es "mysql".
- host -> El host, Ip del servidor.
- Database -> el nombre de la base de datos.
- charset -> Especificar el charset utilizado en la conexión (esto si quires lo quitas).
- UID -> nombre de usuario.
- PWD -> contraseña de usuario.

Vista formulario.

Archivo "form.php":

```
<?php

include 'conectardb.php';

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Personal");
$query->execute();
$users = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="es">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <select>
                <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
                <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= $user['Codigo'] ?>"><?= $user['Nombre'] . ' ' . $user['Apellido1'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Explicación:

En la variable `$query` hacemos la consulta de coger todos los datos de la tabla "Personal".

Con `execute` ejecutamos la sentencia.

Ahora esos registros recogidos los convertimos a un array asociativo con `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Espero ayudar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a probarlo y en un rato te digo :)